# Necesito armar un SQL phpmyadmin para listar una tabla con las empresas y contratos que les toque pagar en el mes actual y que si ya pago no lo liste

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

```
SELECT  a.cod_contrato, a.cod_anunciante, a.presupuesto, b.cod, b.mcuota, date_format(b.mesdpago,'%d-%m-%Y') AS mesdpago, c.cod, c.nom, c.cor1, c.tel1 FROM espacios_publicitarios.anunciantes AS c INNER JOIN espacios_publicitarios.contratos AS a ON a.cod_anunciante = c.cod INNER JOIN espacios_publicitarios.ppto_cuotas AS b ON a.presupuesto = b.cod left JOIN espacios_publicitarios.pagos AS d ON d.contrato = a.cod_contrato   WHERE  b.mesdpago  LIKE '%2018-10%'
```

Tengo las siguientes tablas

- anunciantes (Informacion de la empresa)
- contratos   (Contratos activos)
- ppto_cuotas (Cuotas de los presupuestos)
- pagos       (Resgitrod d pagos de cada cuota correspondiente )

Solo necesito el SQL, con el que tengo actualmente lista a todos así ya hayan pagado..

hasta ahora no logro relacionar las demas tablas con de pagos lo que quiero es que me muestre (Quienes le tienen cuota en el mes actual y no han pagado aun)

de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la función MONTH(): Devuelve el mes de una fecha, en el rango de 1 a 12.

Documentación:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Uso:

Una opción seria convertir la fecha en mes y pasarle como parámetro la fecha actual también convertido en mes.

Script:

`select * from tabla where MONTH(fecha) = MONTH(now())`

Answer (score 0):

En tu tabla debes tener un campo **estado** o algo similar, con valores como estos **pagada** o **debe**. En el `WHERE  b.mesdpago  LIKE '%2018-10%'`  agregas `AND estado = debe`

Comment: No tengo un campo con estado solo con la fecha de pago válido si pagó o no el pago correspondiente en el mes.

Comment: Prueba con  `WHERE  b.mesdpago  LIKE '%2018-10%' AND b.mesdpago IS NOT NULL`

Comment: O con `WHERE  b.mesdpago  LIKE '%2018-10%' AND b.mesdpago <> ""`